# ViewChild elementRef undefined even on ngAfterViewInit in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am upgrading the code from Angular 5 to Angular 8 and I am facing a strange issue(scrollContainer and scrollWrapper are both undefined in ngAfterViewInit):

component.ts

```
@ViewChild('timelineScrollContainer',{ static: true}) set controlElRef(elementRef: ElementRef) {
this.scrollContainer = elementRef;
}

@ViewChild('timelineScroll',{ static: true}) set controlElWrapRef(elementRef: ElementRef) {
this.scrollWrapper = elementRef;
}

ngOnInit() {
this.initTimelineMonths();
this.isLoaded = true;
}

initTimelineMonths() {
  //Populate months array
  this.months = [];
}

ngAfterViewInit() { 
//scrollTimeLineToItem uses the elementRef of scrollContainer 
this.scrollTimeLineToItem(this.monthBoxComponents.last, false);
}
```

component.html

```
<div class="timeline-scroll-wrapper" #timelineScroll *ngIf="months">
<div class="bar-labels label-left">
  <span>Federal</span>
  <span>State</span>
  <span>24 Month</span>
</div>
<div class="bar-labels label-right">
  <span>Federal</span>
  <span>State</span>
  <span>24 Month</span>
</div>
<div class="timeline-scroll-container" #timelineScrollContainer>
  <app-month-box *ngFor="let item of months; let i = index;"></app-month-box>
</div>
```

What is wrong here?
Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks

Comment: What `console.log(this.scrollContainer)` shows if you put it at the start of the `ngAfterViewInit`? Can you make simple repro on stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `component.ts`, do the following changes.

```
@ViewChild('timelineScroll', { static: false }) divTimelineScrollRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
@ViewChild('timelineScrollContainer', { static: false }) divTimelineScrollContainerRef: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

...
```

Comment: Thanks Uminder, yes this solved my issue, but not sure what was wrong with my previous code, i initially tried @ViewChild('timelineScroll', { static: false }) divTimelineScrollRef: ElementRef; but that didnt solve my problem, the only difference I see that made this work was specifying ElementRef<HTMLDivElement> instead of ElementRef.

Comment: You probably also had 'static: true' that resolves query results before change detection runs